# Help With Overriding C# .NET

Tags: c#, overriding

I need to override Tabcontrol GetTabRect.

```
  protected override Rectangle GetTabRect(int index)
    {...}
```

I receive this error

> Error 1 'TabControl.GetTabRect(int)':
>   cannot change access modifiers when
>   overriding 'public' inherited member
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.GetTabRect(int)'
>
> Error2'TabControl.GetTabRect(int)':
>   cannot override inherited member
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.GetTabRect(int)'
>   because it is not marked virtual,
>   abstract, or override

How can I do this?

EDIT

if i use public:

```
TabControl.GetTabRect(int)': cannot override inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.GetTabRect(int)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override
```

Comment: The method is not marked as `virtual` so you cannot override it (regardless of access modifiers)

Comment: @Ste: It was not meant to be overridden

Comment: Couldn't he use public new Rectangle GetTabRect(int index)?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: That would *hide* the base class method, but not *override* it - that means if you access his class with a reference typed to the base class, the base class method would still execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabControl.GetTabRect()` method is public and it's non-virtual so you may need to find a different solution to the problem you're trying to solve. Even if you override this method using the `new` keyword, the base class will still not call your implementation because it's not a virtual function.

You could try handling the `DrawItem` event and render the tab yourself - it's probably more work but it gives you control over how the tab is rendered and then you can use any bounding rectangle that you want.

What are you trying to do that needs an overridden `GetTabRect()` method?

Answer (score 4):

The method is public. So you can't make it protected when you're overriding it. So you have to keep the public visibility.

It should look like this:

```
public override Rectangle GetTabRect(int index)
```

Comment: +1 of course and talking code wise it means having `public override Rectangle GetTabRect(int index)`

Comment: cheers, need to remember those obvious things are not obvious to everyone. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're effectively hiding the function with your override. You need to maintain the `public` nature of the function as you cannot change the signiature when you override a method.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have got seems to clearly state that you cannot restrict/change the access when you override the method.
You can override it as Public.
Is there a specific reason why you want your GetTabRect needs to be protected?